# How to redirect standard output to a variable and a file at the same time?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

This question comes from **Pro Bash Programming** by **Chris Johnson** at **Chapter 2 Exercises 2**:

Write a script, using $RANDOM, to write the following output both to a file and to a variable. The following numbers are only to show the format; your script should produce different numbers:

```
 1988.2365
13798.14178
10081.134
 3816.15098
```

Here is my solution:

```
printf -v var "%5d.%-5d\n" $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM > FILE
```

It seems that the output directly goes into var, FILE is empty.

My question is that is there a way to redirect standard output to a variable and a file **at the same time**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write:

```
var="$(printf '%5d.%-5d\n' $RANDOM ... | tee FILE)"
```

using [the `tee` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) to "split" standard-output, so that it goes both into `FILE` and into a new standard-output that can be captured in your variable using [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution).

Comment: @47dev47null Did this work for you in a script, or just through the command line? If I type this in the command line, it "works", although the format of text in var is incorrect (no newlines, just spaces between each of the numbers). However, if I run this exact same command in a script (same command, but top of file has #!/bin/bash ), var is empty afterward. If I print var from inside the script, it's ok. Any idea why var doesn't remain set after running the script? Thanks!

Comment: @MikeBell: Re: "the format of text in var is incorrect (no newlines, just spaces between each of the numbers)": Sounds like you forgot the double-quotes `"..."`. Re: "Any idea why var doesn't remain set after running the script?": That's always the case. A Bash script is a standalone program, not part of the shell that invokes it. A standalone program cannot modify the environment of the invoking program. (If you want to define variables in separate files, you can use the `.` or `source` builtin, which reads a file and runs its contents as Bash commands inside the current shell.)

Comment: @ruakh Thanks a lot for the clarification! You're right--if I do <echo "$var"> rather than <echo $var> in the script, the contents of var are shown correctly. Thanks again!